# Setup mail for lamp

Tags: 14.04, lamp, sendmail

I am trying to setup mail mail for my server but when i try to run command `sudo apt install sendmail` it gives me

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i have done all updation but it error remains the same

Comment: try `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: @damadam tried it

Comment: You have of course used a search engine and searched for this problem before asking?

Comment: Try: `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

Comment: @MatsK i m searching it for a while but can not get any solution